# Boxes not aligning: html email

Tags: html-email

I have an html email template I am working on. For some reason the boxes do not line up. I assume is a box sizing issue or padding is being added... Here is the code:

```
<table width="700px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#e85728" align="center" style="width: 700px;" class="dashedBorder">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="350px" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e85728" height="298" align="center" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; white-space: normal; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; width: 350px;"><br />
        <font size="4" color="#ffffff">
        <font size="4" color="#ffffff">Use your CAP-VIA discount coupon & be entered into a draw to win a $5,000 trip with VIA Rail.</font>
        &nbsp;</font>
        <table width="167" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="33" align="center" style="box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px #888888; border-radius: 6px;" class="dashedBorder">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; padding: 5px 10px;" 2"=""><b><font color="00698f"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.icc-icc.ca" title="ENTER TO WIN NOW" alias="ENTER TO WIN NOW" conversion="false"><font color="00698f">ENTER TO WIN NOW</font></a></font></b></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <font size="4" color="#ffffff">
        <p>
        <font size="2" color="#ffffff"><u><a style="text-decoration: none;" false"="" alias="Find out how to enter " title="Find out how to enter " href="http://www.icc.ca"><font color="#ffffff">Find out how to enter 
        </font></a></u></font>
        </p>
        </font></td>
        <td width="350px" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="" align="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; width: 350px; white-space: normal;">
        <table width="50" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="100" class="dashedBorder">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="" align="left" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; white-space: normal;"><img width="350" vspace="0" border="0" hspace="0" height="300" alt="Image_350x300px" title="Image_350x300px" src="http://image.S7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9c13727565047e73/m/1/Image_350x300px.jpg" style="width: 350px; height: 300px;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table to the right is set to a width of 50. I assume you want it at 350 like the table on the left?

```
<table width="50" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="100" class="dashedBorder">
```

Needs to be:

```
<table width="350" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="100" class="dashedBorder">
```